# Sent All Variables in Controller Function to the View

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-5

I have a function in my controller. I created a lot of variables, and send them to my view via `compact` function one by one.

---

```
public function edit($id,$cpe_mac) {

        $vcpe = VSE::vcpe($cpe_mac);
        $vcpe = json_decode (json_encode($vcpe), FALSE);
        $cpe = VSE::cpe($cpe_mac);
        $wan = $cpe['wan'];
        $acl = $cpe['acl'];
        $guest = $cpe['vlan'][0];
        $private = $cpe['vlan'][1];
        $cpe_name = VSE::cpe_name($cpe_mac)['cpe_name'];
        $p_max_up = $private['bandwidth']['max_up'];
        $p_max_down = $private['bandwidth']['max_down'];
        $p_ip = $private['lan']['ip_address'];
        $p_netmask = $private['lan']['netmask'];
        $p_max_clients = $private['lan']['dhcp_server']['max_clients'];
        $p_dns = $private['lan']['dhcp_server']['dns'][0];
        $p_dns2 = $private['lan']['dhcp_server']['dns'][1];
        $cpe = json_decode (json_encode($cpe), FALSE);

        return view('cpe.edit', compact(['vcpe','cpe_mac','cpe_name','cpe','wan','acl','private','guest',
            'p_max_up','p_max_down','p_ip','p_netmask','p_max_clients','p_dns','p_dns2'

        ]));

}
```

---

**Question**

Is there a way to send **all** the variables to the view rather than doing it one by one ?

Comment: You can put all those values in an array and pass this to the view, actually you do this already when you pass a returned collection to the view. Is just the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following...

```
return view('cpe.edit', get_defined_vars());
```

There might be some unnecessary overhead though if you are creating a lot of variables which you would not otherwise need in your view.

Comment: That's it. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the heads up, I only create the variables that I will need in the view, so your suggestion perfectly match what I am looking for. This is beautiful. I wish I know this long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify you can do this

```
// BaseController
protected $data = array();

// Controller
$this->data = array(
    'variable' => $variable, 
    // ...
);

return View::make('example', $this->data);
```

But I dont think there is more simpler way or I am not aware.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to send all the variables to the view.